# how to setup ssh proxy by user in k8

Tags: ssh, nginx, kubernetes

I currently host gitlab in kubernetes, and would also like to move an sftp service there. I would like to host both with a single load balancer and (nginx) ingress.

The problem is that nginx ingress can only forward port 22 to one destination. My plan to resolve this is to set up a proxy service in k8, forwarded to by nginx, that forwards "git" user to gitlab, and all other users to the sftp service.

Is this possible? How should I setup (sshd_config, in particular)?

Also, is it possible to forward credentials -- e.g. if some user uses a ssh key they have configured for use in gitlab, it will recognize them as that user. Sftp users use passwords. I would like to make sure that the client "ssh" command results in the credentials the end user has available are used with the target ssh host. In particular, I want to make sure that sftp clients (which are our business clients, using automated scripts in some cases) don't have to change anything to connect. (NB -- I'll be reassigning IPs and setting up host keys so that load balancer and proxy "look" the same from the outside as far at that is feasible.)